# Show that the set $A = \{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 + x_2 > 0\}$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the usual Euclidean metric, then the set $$A = \{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 + x_2 > 0\}$$
is open.

I'm really stumped on this. :/

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with? Can you draw a picture of relevant region?

Comment: Have you ever tried listing out the definition of open sets?

Comment: Hello! I know that the region is basically everything above the line y = -x in R2. I was trying to come up with a proof that relies on open balls, but I've never actually done that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y) = x+y$, thus $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ and look at $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ and $f$ is continuous, and $(0,\infty)$ is "open". So its preimage is open also.

Comment: Do you know why they write "Prove that if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the usual Euclidean metric"?
when
"The metric topology on $\mathbb{E}$ is called the Euclidean topology, and it is identical to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: Sir is it a theorem , i have read a similar theoram for connectedness.That theorem says image of a continuous function is connected if the domain is connected.Is there an analogous theorem for compactness and the closed sets as well?